# Can I use dd to the drive it's running from?

Tags: linux, dd

This question is the reverse of [this question.](https://superuser.com/questions/383166/can-i-dd-from-my-current-hard-drive-to-another-hard-drive-while-running-the-os)

Let's say I have an image file. `example.img`, stored in a server that is accessible with ssh, rsync, and wget (whichever works). 
Then you have a PC with running linux (say, Ubuntu.)

The question, can I dd from that `example.img` to the existing machine over ssh or wget?  
Will this command

```
wget http://example.com/files/example.img | dd of=/dev/sda
```

work, when the linux is actually on `/dev/sda`? 
and if  `example.img` is bootable, will the machine able to boot the result, considering if the `example.img` itself is made from this machine's `/dev/sda` before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dd'ing to running machine ends with kernel panic, and the disk is unusable.

when the linux is at /dev/sda, and we're running dd if=something of=/dev/sda, it'll hangs at half the progress and then kernel panic itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear exactly what you are asking, so I'll work through the possibilities -

If the image file contains a dusk image including partitions, as opposed to just the contents if a partition, and if the hardware is similar enough (ie correct drivers - much less if an issue for Linux then Windows) and there are no license related issues (ie Windows license keys on different hardware) - if you can fully copy the image, it will work.  **Despite caviates here this kind of thing is common for VM management**

The next issue is one of destination drive - you would not want the OS to be currently running off the target drive, so you need to be booted off zUSB, an alternative dtivr of PXE/network boot. Booting to an existing active drive will likely leave it in an inconsistent state with hidden problems.

Actually copying the image is not that hard - you simy stream it (for example across ssh) and write it out to the disk block device. There are lots of options here, and you can include things like compression, progress monitoring, speed limiting. A very simple command might be:

```
 ssh root@ip.addr "cat /path/to/file.img" > /dev/sdX
```

Because ssh writes prompts to stderr, this can work even if a password us required. Of-course, you can do the SSH in either direction and use pipes to control the stream - I like using PV to show progress for example.

Comment: basically the question is I wanted to overwrite the system that's currently running, and not possible to use recovery / live disk. is there a typo on your answer? I'm confused reading it lol

Comment: Overwriting the current system is a bad idea and may not end well -  I would not recommend attempting it. That said if it's do or die, you can greatly  reduce the risks by going to a single user (or at least no GUI) mode , ensuring as little is running as possible and hard rebooting once the copy is complete. Again though, I would not recommend this.

Comment: overwriting the system results in kernel panic when done in itself. when the linux is at /dev/sda and we're overwriting /dev/sda, it'll just kernel panic before it finishes.